# Play Framework app can't be deployed when ssh session stopped

Tags: scala, ubuntu, playframework-2.0, server, production

I am trying to deploy a play framework app on my remote virtual private server hosted by OVH. My VPS is on ubuntu 14.10 server. Therefore, I read the documentation and I used the command line: `activator start` instead of `activator run` to deploy in production my app. I can see the page loaded on the 9000 port however once I stop my SSH session, the website is down. Is that normal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to press CTRL+D after the server is started?

Please read this:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/Production

Answer (score 0):

Not much in common with Playframework here. This is a basic process question.

You have to detach the process from your ssh tty. You can use different tools to do that :

- [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)
- [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)
- [nohup](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/nohup-invocation.html)
- systemd
- init.d scripts

Also checkout [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely) from Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
nohup activator start &
```